# Scroll position is not saved in Grdiview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-view, scroll-position

Can somebody please help me I have an issue in scroll of GridView What I do is I show the first 10 products in GridView from the API.. Now what I need is - When the user scrolls and gets the last position of list then API hits again with page value 2 .. and the scroll shows from the current position where the user is.. Now Data is shown and Adapter changes its value.. But scroll shows on the top when the new API hits... Can anyone please tell me What is to be done??? Really Appreciated please help..

what I do -

```
        grid.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        int last_item;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int   scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)      {


            int lastitem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
            if(lastitem == totalItemCount){

                       HitApi();//This is the method where API hits with the new page value


            }


        }
    });
```

xml file

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <GridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/products_GridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        >
       </GridView>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are aiming for! do you need to save the scroll position when the user navigate to another activity and get back to the gridView activity ? what do you mean by page value 2? can u show us a demo or screen-shots that better describes the situation

Comment: No , i am not going to next activity .. Just my adapter data changes with the new values and every time when I scroll and data changes the scroll  is at the top. and it will start from where the new data loads or added to the list

Comment: I would assume that u are using a scrollView right ? is it in a linearLayout? please share with us your xml

Comment: I am using simple Gridview .please check

Comment: Also include your notifyDataSetChanged() if its the way that you use to update the list or include the list update method :)

Comment: Where should I use notifyDataSetChanged ? On scrollListener?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are updating the data in the list dynamically so u already are using it if not where do you update your listView ? what does the hitApi contain? the reason I'm asking you all of that is the listView already handles scroll position by default and it preserve it, in your case it doesn't so its probably something wrong with code so I've to see the code to figure out what have gone wrong

Comment: Yes i am updating the list before setting the adapter to the gridview... And HitApi method contains the AsynTask class where the url hits with updated value of page so that the list contains the  next values as well

Comment: I've added my ans hope it will help you, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so assuming that `hitApi()` updates the `ListView` with the new items, then the method will probably call `.clear()` on the current list which will cause the problem and then it will add the new items; what you have to do here to keep the last position is adding this before `hitApi()` method:

```
int i = yourList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = yourList.getChildAt(0);
int t = 0;
if(v!=null)v.getTop();
```

Then after calling the `hitApi()` method, set up the old position back:

```
yourList.setSelectionFromTop(i, t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    /***
     * LodeMore Variables
     */
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private int visibleThreshold = 1;
    private int index = 1;
    private boolean loading;

 private void initLodeMoreAdapter()
    {

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof GridLayoutManager)
        {

            final GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (GridLayoutManager) rvResponse.getLayoutManager();
            rvResponse.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy)
                {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);


                    totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (!loading &&totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))
                    {
                        // End has been reached
                        // Do something
            loading = true;
                        getResponseListing();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

 private void getResponseListing()
    {
        if (utility.isNetworkAvailable())
        {
        API Call...

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        loading = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this in your adapter to get last visible position

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
  ...
  int previouslyDisplayedPosition = -1;
  ...

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     if(previouslyDisplayedPosition != position) {
      ....

      previouslyDisplayedPosition = position;
     }

     return convertedView;
   }
```

Just an idea. Not sure will it work or not. Just a work around

Comment: Why minus? Any reason? You can get position while it has been scrolled. Get the current position